# Mysql backup error

Tags: mysql, backup

I wrote the below line to create a mysql backup , for some reasons i'm getting Errcode 13 .

```
  E:\Xampp\xampp\mysql\bin\\mysqldump -u root --add-drop-database -B project_db -r C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\a.sql
```

Why does the above line fail to execute ? I'm trying to create a DB backup using the above line ? Pls Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because file "C:\Documents" does not exist. You probably want this:

```
-r "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\a.sql"
   ^                                                          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

E:\Xampp\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u root --add-drop-database -B project_db > "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\a.sql"

Answer (score 0):

" " were missing

E:\Xampp\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u root --add-drop-database -B project_db -r "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\a.sql"

above command may work